# How to switch editor language specification to cljs?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojurescript, cursive

I am using the latest Cursive for clojurescript development. I found the auto-complete popup can never resolve `js` namespace while in the *.cljs files.

[image]

But it works in nREPL when I switch the language to `cljs` by clicking the dropdown menu on the top-right corner.

[image]

So, how could I switch the editor language specification of *.cljs files to `cljs`?